# JQuery Promise Interface for a (very) simple JSON Parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, json

I have written a parser function that returns a JQuery Promise.  You can see from the code that this is the top level parser and it delegates out to two other more specific parsers.

At the minute it feels a little scattered about with the promise being rejected and resolved all over the place.  perhaps it would be better with a try and catch and an error handler that rejected the promsie?  how would others approach this?

```
/**
 * Inspects JSON and delegates to either the sourceParser or the dataParser.
 * 
 * @constructor 
 * @param {Object} json
 * 
 * @returns JQuery Promsise
 *      done:       -
 *      fail:       error message
 *      progress:   Progress message
 */
function Parser(json)
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    dfd.notify("Parsing");

    if (json && typeof json === "object")
    {           
        if (json.hasOwnProperty("GetDataSources"))
        {           
            var dataSource = json.GetDataSources;

            if (this.isSuccessfulResponse(dataSource.Response))
            {
                // Notify the caller of any progress
                dfd.notify("Parsing Source");

                // Create a new Source Parser
                var sourceParser =  new SourceParser(dataSource);
                sourceParser.done(dfd.resolve);
                sourceParser.fail(dfd.reject);
            }
            else
            {
                dfd.reject("Parsing Source Failed");
            }
        }
        else if (json.hasOwnProperty("GetData"))
        {           
            var data = json.GetData;

            if (this.isSuccessfulResponse(data.Response))
            {
                // Notify the caller of any progress
                dfd.notify("Parsing Data");

                // Create a new Data Parser
                var dataParser = new DataParser(data);
                dataParser.done(dfd.resolve);
                dataParser.fail(dfd.reject);
            }
            else
            {
                // Pass back an error message?
                dfd.reject("Parsing Data Failed");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dfd.reject("There was a problem reading the JSON")
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chop up functions longer than 12 lines of code into smaller functions.
Since you're using `this`, then you can attach the additional functions to the prototype on `Parser`.

Here's what I came up with.

```
function Parser(json) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    dfd.notify("Parsing");
    if (json && typeof json === "object") {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty("GetDataSources")) {
            this._handleData( dfd, json.GetDataSources, SourceParser, "Source" );
        } else if (json.hasOwnProperty("GetData")) {
            this._handleData( dfd, json.GetData, DataParser, "Data" );
        }
    } else {
        dfd.reject("There was a problem reading the JSON");
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}
Parser.prototype._handleData = function(dfd, data, OtherParser, type){
    if (data && this.isSuccessfulResponse(data.Response)) {
        dfd.notify("Parsing " + type );
        var otherParser = new OtherParser(data);
        otherParser.done(dfd.resolve);
        otherParser.fail(dfd.reject);
    } else {
        dfd.reject("Parsing "+ type +" Failed");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Larry.  I had improved the code since posting it here but your approach is even better still.  I have a tendency to create promises on top of promises unnecessarily! and I liked passing the parser as an Argument.

Comment: one thing though sinsided the hasOwnProperty functions should they be something like dfd = this._handleData otherwise the dfd object gets lost.

Comment: It's not really needed because objects are passed by reference  and primitive values are passed by value in javascript. But I like returning the value of `dfd` to check the output since `dfd` is a private member. However, if `return dfd;` causes confusion then take it out.

Comment: have I mentioned that this is awesome?

Comment: Out of interest, Parser is a constructor function, do you see anything wrong with it returning a promise rather than an instance of itself?

Comment: @CrimsonChin I removed the return since it's causing confusing and not necessary.